# Evaluate the integration $\int_0^\pi \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(x)) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I need to evaluate the value of $$\int_0^\pi \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos{(x)}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x$$ and show this is less than $\pi/2$.

I know this is equal to $\pi J_0(\pi/2)\approx 1.48$ by computer calculator where $J_0$ is the Bessel function. But I do know little about the insight of Bessel function and I do not know how to calculate (or evaluate) $J_0(\pi/2)$. I would appreciate it a lot if any help were offered.

Comment: The Bessel function is just another function—like sin, cos, tan, log—and the fact that you're not as familiar with it suggests you should learn about it rather than try to avoid it.  As a start, just plot it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I found that this integral is equal to $$ \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n(n!)^2} \left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right)^{2n} $$ using Taylor Series of $\cos{x}$ now I want to write  $$ \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n(n!)} \frac{x^n}{n!} $$ in terms of HyperGeometric function, but .......

Comment: See that $$ \int_0^\pi \cos \left(  \frac{\pi}{2} \cos{(x)} \right) dx = 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos \left(  \frac{\pi}{2} \cos{(x)} \right) dx $$

Comment: Plotting this function shows it looks very similar to the plot of $\sin^2x$. All you have to do is show that $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x\right) \leq \sin^2 x$$ with equality iff $x$ is an integer multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: My goodness!  You're more comfortable with an intermediate result of $\frac{\pi}{2} \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n(n!)^2} \left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right)^{2n}$ than with a final result of a single Bessel function!  This is *so* different from nearly all of my students.  Anyway, good luck with your infinite sum!  The Bessel is "almost" the same as a sine:  What a sine is to a one-dimensional string, a Bessel is to a two-dimensional circular drumhead.  Nothing to be afraid of!

Comment: @LuckyChouhan. I am not sure that the result could be $$\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n!)^2} \left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right)^{2n}$$

Comment: Thank you all for so brilliant ideas! I had been studying equations and forgot these methods to evaluate. Plotting does help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the series expansion of the most outside cosine,
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(x))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac 1{(2n)!}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 n} \cos ^{2 n}(x)$$

Using $$\int_0^\pi \cos ^{2 n}(x)\,dx=\sqrt{\pi }\,
\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$ the integral is
$$\sqrt{\pi }\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac 1{(2n)!}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 n} \,
\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$

$$a_n=\frac 1{(2n)!}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 n} \,
\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)}\quad \implies \quad \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\pi ^2}{16 (n+1)^2}$$

For sure, the result is $\pi\,  J_0\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$.

But, if you consider the partial sum
$$S_p=\sqrt{\pi }\,\sum_{n=0}^p (-1)^n \frac 1{(2n)!}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 n} \,
\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$ you will notice that it converges very fast to the exact value.

Using $p=10$, the result is $\color{red}{1.4828355519429372}315$

You could even know in advance how many terms have to be added in order to have
$$a_{p+1}\leq 10^{-k}$$ since, taking logarithms and using Stirling approximation you need to solve for $p$ the equation
$$2 p \left(\log \left(\frac{4 p}{\pi }\right)-1\right)=k\,\log(10)$$ the solution of which being given in terms of Lambert function.
$$p\sim \frac{k \log (10)}{2 W\left(\frac{2k \log (10)}{e \pi }\right)}$$

For $k=20$, this gives $p=12.8361$, that is to say $13$ terms to be added.

To give an idea of the approximation, the exact solution is $p=11.2564$

Comment: $(+1)$ That's what I was saying $$\int_0^\pi \cos \left(  \frac{\pi}{2} \cos{(x)} \right) dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^{2n} \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2) \sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(n+1)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{(-1)^n}{n(n!)^2} \left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right)^{2n} $$ because $$\Gamma(n+1/2) = \frac{(2n-1)! \sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n} n!} $$ I really like your asymptotic analysis :)

Comment: @LuckyChouhan. I do not agree with your last formula. Moreover, your summation starts at $n=0$? Cheers :-)

Comment: Oui, Thank you for correcting me! I just realised.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\int_0^\pi\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x\right)dx=2\int_0^1\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}u\right)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$$ Think about how you can bound $$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}u\right)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$